# Need to display the size of my HashSet to a TextView

Tags: java, arrays

I am able to log the size of my array inside the console. However, I cannot output the size of my array to  a TextView.

I tried to implement it by doing this:

```
System.out.println("Sise of HashSet : " + list.size()); ------ Works in console
            text1.setText(list.size()); ------- Does not work / crashes app
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing

```
text1.setText(list.size() + "");
```

or

```
text1.setText(String.valueOf(list.size()));
```

When you call `System.out.println` it works because the out object (of type PrintWriter) has an overloaded println(..) method for all primitive types. However, in your case having

```
System.out.println("Size of HashSet : " + list.size());
```

makes parameter of println() method convert to string. It is detailed explained in [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/converting.html) link.

On the other hand, setText() of a TextView expects String and you are passing it an integer.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why the OP's first statement works.

Comment: Or could it be because the first statement has `"some string" + aNumber`, thus causing automatic conversion of the number to a string, whereas the second statement only has a number? I don't know for sure myself: I just googled "java coerce to string" and looked over some results.

Comment: @AndrewMorton you are right (+1), in this case this is it. However, the overloaded method would make it work in case you had only integer as a parameter of println() method.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So I should change the setText to setInt? This is day 3 of Java programming I apologize for any inconvenience.

Comment: No, you don't have that method. just add .toString() after .size()

Comment: Something like this? : text1.setString(list.size.ToString());

Comment: SOrry. Like this? : text1.setString(list.size().ToString());

Comment: I used this: text1.setText(list.size().toString());  But I got an error saying "Cannot Invoke toString() on the primitive type int" Does that make sense to you?

Comment: Yes Miki. That worked. Thank you for your time and patience my friend.

Comment: On a side not. I don't know why I bother going to school. This website is better than any teachers I have had. Thanks again.

Comment: School is good, use this site when you have problems only. And remember to vote up helpful answers too ;)